# I am getting error of "Cannot reolve symbol 'resid' and 'show()' :"

Tags: android

I am getting error as "Cannot reolve symbol 'resid' and 'show()' :".

```
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

        if(task.isSuccessful()){

            sendToMain();

        } else {

            String errorMessage = task.getException().getMessage();
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, resid:"Error : " + 
                   errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         }

        reg_progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

         }
    });

 } else {

   Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, resid:"Confirm Password and 
      Password Field doesn't Match.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 }
```

Comment: what is resid  here ?

Comment: sorry sir i don't know about it i'am just practicing one tutorial code but he doesn't replayed me.... you did..

Comment: Does your error actually "resolve" symbol? If so, please repair the two instances of it - and **always copy+paste your errors**.

Comment: hi sir thanks for replaying my question... my error has resolved by @Raj sir 
once again thanks --Halfer-- sir...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, resid + ": Confirm Password and 
Password Field doesn't Match.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Or

```
Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "resid: Confirm Password and 
Password Field doesn't Match.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

depending on what is resid. I hope you get it

Comment: So you should mark the answer as accepted. As resid acts as a variable here . and colons should be as - ":"

Comment: oh thanks this line resolved but "resid" is staying there only like.............          

Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, text: resid + ": Confirm Password and Password Field doesn't Match.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: If resid is a variable then you have to do as - resid + "Confirm...." . resid value is concatenated with string.

Comment: thanks for replying again sir... i am having the same error, even adding the code as you suggested... "cannot resolve symbol 'resid' but 'show()' is clearing...

Comment: you have to declare resid  variable.  as int resid = 0; And you are done with your error.

Comment: yes it's done sir.... very very thanks... will you give me some continues support like this sir... i am a starter only...